# What is the correct way to access class variable inside class method? self.class_variable or class_name.class_variable?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, class-variables

```
class Employee:
    location = "south"

    def describe(self):
        print(self.location)
```

Should I use self.class_variable to access class variable inside class method?

```
class Employee:
    location = "south"

    def describe(self):
        print(Employee.location)
```

Or rather I should be using class_name.class_variable?
Which one is the correct convention?
Is there even a difference between the two?

Edit 1:
So besides other answers that people have given I have found that
if you change self.class_variable, it will change it for just that instance
and if you change class_name.class_variable, it will change it for all the current and future instances.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The difference becomes relevant if you subclass:

```
>>> class Employee:
...     location = "south"
...     def describe_self(self):
...         print(self.location)
...     def describe_class(self):
...         print(Employee.location)
...
>>> class Salesman(Employee):
...     location = "north"
...
>>> Employee().describe_self()
south
>>> Employee().describe_class()
south
>>> Salesman().describe_self()
north
>>> Salesman().describe_class()
south
```

since if you subclass, the type of `self` may not actually be `Employee`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a difference between the two.

```
class Employee:
    location = "south"


class EmployeeSelf(Employee):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.location


class EmployeeEmployee(Employee):
    def __str__(self):
        return Employee.location


emp = EmployeeSelf()
emp.location = 'north'
print(emp)

emp0 = EmployeeEmployee()
emp0.location = 'north'
print(emp0)
```

Have a look at this example. Whilst the identifier `self` points at the object itself the `Employee` identifier points to the class.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.